# What happens if I attach the same events to the same elements?

Tags: javascript

It will perform the search two times? Or it will overwrites the first listener?

`element.onclick = () => { search(); }
 element.onclick = () => { search(); }`

or

`element.addEventListener('click', () => { search(); })
 element.addEventListener('click', () => { search(); })`

Comment: That the first one exists is a bad design decision that caused a lot of headache in the last years.

Comment: this would be a very very simple experiment that takes maybe one minute to test.

Answer (score 4):

`element.onclick = () => {}` overwrites the handler.

If you don't want to overwrite it, use [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('button')

element.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('1st event handler')
})

element.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log('2nd event handler')
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: I've added the two cases.

Comment: And I've explained the difference nonetheless :)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the stupid question, please if you can delete my question, I don't want to be banned. Thank you

Comment: It's not a stupid question. I've got bitten by this many times when I was starting out as well.

Comment: thank you, so if I want to avoid duplicated callbacks, do you recommend to use `onclick`? Because check if an element have an event it's difficult to know in large projects.

Comment: I **never** recommend using `onclick = doSomething` because someone else that maintains your code might inadvertently overwrite your handler. Use `addEventListener` and simply take care when writing your code to avoid duplicate callbacks, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I understand, it's a easy way to fix that but very dangerous. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you think `addEventListener` is dangerous? As long as your code has some unit tests to verify you don't do anything gnarly then you're good to go. `onclick = doSomething` is far more dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning property overwrites the listener:

```
element.onclick = () => { search(); }
```

But setting listener like this add the listener in the queue (duplicates also) and they all executes.

```
element.addEventListener('click',() => { search(); });
```

Answer (score -1):

EventListeners will be called in exact order they are attached to the element.

```js
const clicker = document.getElementById('clicker')

clicker.addEventListener('click', () => { alert('Fired first time') })
clicker.addEventListener('click', () => { alert('Fired second time') })
```

```html
<button id="clicker">Click me</button>
```